# Does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

> Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}$ coverges or diverges?

Could you give me some hints? Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's an alternating series. Do you know any tests specific to alternating series?

Comment: But the Leibniz test does not apply, all you commenters.

Comment: It does not fit into the setting of the alternating series test, but you can decompose the series as a sum of alternating series and absolutely convergent series. One trick is to multiply $n - (-1)^n \sqrt{n+1}$ to both the numerator and to the denominator. Or, if you know about big-Oh notation, you can do much easier as in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. As $n \to \infty$, one may write, by using a Taylor expansion,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}} &=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{1+(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n}
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cdot \left(1+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}} \right) \right)
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}} \right)
\end{align}
$$ thus the initial series is a *conditionally convergent* series being the sum of a *conditionally convergent* series and an *absolute convergent* series.